# Get all values from array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

I have a table array $users(id, name, email, password, avatar, created_at, updated_at, roles);

I would like to assign this array of values from `User::latest()->get();`

So I wrote something with an anonymous function in array key `'roles'` below:

```
    $data = User::latest()->get();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($data as $user){
        $users[$i] = [
            'id' => $user->id,
            'name' => $user->name,
            'email' => $user->email,
            'password' => $user->password,
            'avatar' => 'default.png',
            'roles' => function(){
                foreach($user->roles as $role){
                    return $role->name;
                }
            },
            'created_at' => $user->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $user->updated_at
            ];
        $i++;
    }
```

But it does not work.

I tried like this:

```
    $data = User::latest()->get();
    $i = 0;
    foreach($data as $user){
        foreach($user->roles as $role){
            $users[$i] = [
                'id' => $user->id,
                'name' => $user->name,
                'email' => $user->email,
                'password' => $user->password,
                'avatar' => 'default.png',
                'roles' => $role->name,
                'created_at' => $user->created_at,
                'updated_at' => $user->updated_at
            ];
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

But in the variable 'roles' get only the last role, not all.

So anyone know how to assign these values ​​to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
       'roles' => array_map(function($role){
                      return $role->name;
                  }, $user->roles),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$user->roles()->pluck('name');` instead. The [`pluck`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-pluck) method will give you a list of all role names of the corresponding user and is "cleaner/easier to read" than any map function in your case.

Answer (score 0):

try this way create an empty array and other array in foreach loop and push that in empty array as follow

```
$userArr = [];
if ($data) {
foreach ($data as $dataobj) {
 $usersArray= [
            "id" => $dataobj->id,
            "name" => $dataobj-name,
            "email" => $dataobj-email,
            "password" => $dataobj-password,
            "avatar" => "default.png",
            "roles" => $role->name,
            "created_at" => $dataobj-created_at,
            "updated_at" => $dataobj-updated_at
        ];
array_push($userArr, $usersArray);
}
```